# Office 2013 Com Add-in Development

Tags: c#, .net, office-2013, comaddin

Currently i have a Office Add-in (com add-in) for Office 2007, Office 2010 written in .NET 2.0.

I need to update the Add-in for Office 2013, can i continue with .net 2.0? or do i need to upgrade to higher version of .net framework.

Thanks

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

using .NET 2.0 is fine and if you do not need any of the new functionality then it will work.

New functionality in 4.0 such as `dynamic` is useful in COM instead of reflection over COM properties. Also if you might need real time functionality in the future then IObservable and Rx support are also useful.